# Mockito: Wanting but not invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to test this method:

```
        if (user != null) {
            userDAO.delete(user);
            sessionService.logout(user.getEmail());
        }
    }
```

this is my Test:

```
    public void deleteTest(){
        doNothing().when(userDAO).delete(user);
        doNothing().when(sessionService).logout("");

        sessionInvalidationDecorator.delete(user);

        verify(userDAO, times(1)).delete(user);
        verify(sessionService, times(1)).logout("");
    }
```

but I get:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
sessionService.logout("");
-> at de.unibremen.swp.controller.SessionInvalidationDecoratorTest.deleteTest(SessionInvalidationDecoratorTest.java:69)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I don't know what I do wrong

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You inject the mocks in your class?

Comment: Are you sure that the parameter you use is "" when you call the logout? Why don't you use Mockito.anyString();?

Comment: Yes I inject the mocks in my test class.
I tried different things, like "", user.getEmail() and anyString() but it didn't work because I get the same Error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you are indicating the value that logout must have, in this case when it is mocked, and referring to `user.getEmail()` is waiting for you to return a `" "` and instead you are returning a string from getEmail

Comment: @A L
Yes there is the problem, I ttriede to change it into user.getEmail() or anyString() but I get the same Eroor as before. Both verifys don't go and I don't really know why

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `user.getMail` does not return the empty string that you verify.

You have to make sure that `user.getMail` returns a string that is equal to the one you verify.

Here is a complete example that works.

```
public class SessionInvalidationDecoratorTest {

    private UserDAO userDAOMock;
    private SessionService sessionServiceMock;

    private SessionInvalidationDecorator sessionInvalidationDecorator;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        userDAOMock = Mockito.mock(UserDAO.class);
        sessionServiceMock = Mockito.mock(SessionService.class);
        sessionInvalidationDecorator = new SessionInvalidationDecorator(userDAOMock, sessionServiceMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteTest() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("mail@some-domain.com");

        sessionInvalidationDecorator.delete(user);

        Mockito.verify(userDAOMock, Mockito.times(1)).delete(user);
        Mockito.verify(sessionServiceMock, Mockito.times(1)).logout("mail@some-domain.com");

    }
}

public class SessionInvalidationDecorator {

    private UserDAO userDAO;
    private SessionService sessionService;

    public SessionInvalidationDecorator(UserDAO userDAO, SessionService sessionService) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            userDAO.delete(user);
            sessionService.logout(user.getEmail());
        }
    }

}

public interface SessionService {

    void logout(String email);

}

public interface UserDAO {

    void delete(User user);

}

public class User {

    private String email;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

}
```